# Python List random choice

Tags: python, random

Looking for a help / solution here.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
c = [1,2,3]
d = [a,b,c]

random.choice(random.choice(d))
```

this gives me 1,2 or 3. But how to find which list variable this random function used out of `a`, `b`, `c` ? how can I use or what is the syntax of the index function for this ? for my program I have to pop the element the random choice returns.

Comment: So just pop directly from the list object that `random.choice()` gave you. You don't need the variable name, only the list object itself.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove something from the randomly chosen list, you don't need to have the variable name. *The list object itself will do*.

In other words, just remove the selected number from the result that `random.choice()` gives you:

```
picked_list = random.choice(d)
picked = random.choice(picked_list)
picked_list.remove(picked)
```

If you must have some kind of name, don't use separate variables for the input lists. Use a dictionary:

```
lists = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [1, 2, 3],
    'c': [1, 2, 3],
}
list_picked = random.choice(lists)  # returns 'a', 'b', or 'c'
picked = random.choice(lists[list_picked])
lists[list_picked].remove(picked)
```

Note that it'll be more efficient to just shuffle your lists up-front (putting them in random order), then pop elements as you need them:

```
d = [a, b, c]
for sublist in d:
    random.shuffle(sublist)

# later on
picked = random.choice(d).pop()  # remove the last element
```

You'll have to figure out what it means to have an *empty* list there though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one absolutely meets my coding criteria.